# Unable to install Angular 6.0.8

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Angular installation failing with the below error and angular is not installed.

> D:\software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64>npm install -g @angular/cli
>   D:\software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\ng ->
>   D:\eclipse\software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
>
> @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall
>   D:\eclipse\software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\node_modules@angular\cli node
>   ./bin/ng-update-message.js
>
> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents): npm
>   WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! @angular/cli@6.0.8
>   postinstall: node ./bin/ng-update-message.js npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely
>   additional log ging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\N96304.LAUNCHER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-06-19T08_39_53_490Z-debug.lo

**Errors in log :**

```html
8474 info lifecycle @angular/cli@6.0.8~postinstall: @angular/cli@6.0.8
8475 verbose lifecycle @angular/cli@6.0.8~postinstall: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8476 verbose lifecycle @angular/cli@6.0.8~postinstall: PATH: D:software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\.bin;D:software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Application Virtualization Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\EHLLAPI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PortalClient\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICAService;C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32;C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\AdminStudio\6.0\ConflictSolver;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Citrix\system32;C:\Program Files\Citrix\System32\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\instantclient_12_2;C:\Program Files\instantclient_12_2;D:software\New folder\Fiddler;D:software\Fiddler
8477 verbose lifecycle @angular/cli@6.0.8~postinstall: CWD: D:software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\node_modules\@angular\cli
8478 silly lifecycle @angular/cli@6.0.8~postinstall: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node ./bin/ng-update-message.js' ]
8479 silly lifecycle @angular/cli@6.0.8~postinstall: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
8480 info lifecycle @angular/cli@6.0.8~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
8481 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\N96304.LAUNCHER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-acb702ed8f4300ec.lock for D:software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\node_modules\.staging
8482 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
8483 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
8484 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
8484 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
8484 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
8484 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
8485 verbose stack Error: @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall: `node ./bin/ng-update-message.js`
8485 verbose stack Exit status 1
8485 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:285:16)
8485 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
8485 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
8485 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
8485 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
8485 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
8485 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
8485 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
8486 verbose pkgid @angular/cli@6.0.8
8487 verbose cwd D:software\node-v8.11.2-win-x64
8488 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
8489 verbose argv "D:\\software\\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\\node.exe" "D:\\software\\node-v8.11.2-win-x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
8490 verbose node v8.11.2
8491 verbose npm  v5.6.0
8492 error code ELIFECYCLE
8493 error errno 1
8494 error @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall: `node ./bin/ng-update-message.js`
8494 error Exit status 1
8495 error Failed at the @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall script.
8495 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
8496 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: need to install node

Comment: Check if you have `node` in path. Open Cmd and write `node`.

Comment: try `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: are you running as an admin?

Comment: >check here [it may help you to solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51473071/9216423)

Answer (score 0):

Please re-install your node.js and retry. Make sure, that you have Node.js in your environmental variable PATH. You can also try to reinstall Angular-CLI.

Comment: I have reinstalled 8.11.3 (includes npm 5.6.0) LTS and 10.4.1 (includes npm 6.1.0) Latest. Both I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Simply add node in your system Variable : variable : node , path : C:\Program Files\nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

CMD --> Run as administrator -->  C:\Program Files\nodejs> npm install -g @angular/cli