# Angular-cli install in window 7 Error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Tying to install angular-cli in Windows 7,but giving below error;
Please help what needs to be done for the same.

```
    C:\Users\admin>npm i -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
npm ERR! @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall: `node ./bin/ng-update-message.js`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-07-23T06_21_58_799Z-debug.log
```

Node version:

```
v8.11.3
```

Npm version:

```
6.2.0
```

Comment: try clearing cache using --  npm cache clean

Comment: yes..i have already tried npm cache clean.

Comment: 1. Run cmd as admin. 2. npm cache clean --force then 3. Install angular cli.

Comment: running as admin only still getting same error..

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10728 check this

Answer (score 0):

> try with this commands

```
npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe-perm=true
npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flow these steps for install angular cli

1. install Node v8.x.x
2. npm install  windows-build-tools -g
3. npm install @angular-devkit/core -g
4. npm install @angular/cli -g

happy coding